# angular how to config proxy with three backend

Tags: angular, proxy, config

I have three backend url:

- localhost:8080/api/search
- localhost:8081/api/searchs
- localhost:8082/api/test

how to config the proxy to access the different backend url in angular2. the following is my current config file in frontend.

```
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "localhost:8080/",
    "secure": false
  },
  "/api/searchs": {
    "target": "localhost:8081/",
    "secure": false
  }
```

but it seems didn't work.

Comment: have you added --proxy-config YOUR_CONFIG_NAME.json to package.json file?